# Mysql Query Select from same column specific range

Tags: mysql

```
1|Health & Fitness
2|Cardiovascular
3|General Fitness
4|Pilates
5|Technology
6|Artificial Intelligence
7|Advance Learning Machines
8|Virtual and Augmented Reality.
```

this is data in my table.

**I want to get data in between Health & Fitness & Technology**

Comment: What is your existing query? What have you tried?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `topics` where `name` IN ('Health & Fitness', 'Technology');

Comment: Just add `Cardiovascular`, `General Fitness` and `Pilates` to your list and you are done

Comment: i have huge amount of record

Comment: @Saad Ahmed - this gives only 2 Rows. They want get all Rows BETWEEN 'Health & Fitness' and 'Technology'

Comment: If there are no other fields in this table, then this task can not be solved, because data in a relation is unsorted and in general can be returned in any order.

Comment: @BerndBuffen exactly i want all record between in this two  'Health & Fitness' and 'Technology'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a query like this

```
   SELECT * FROM topics
    where
      id >= ( SELECT id from topics WHERE name = 'Health & Fitness')
    AND
      id <= ( SELECT id from topics WHERE name = 'Technology')
    order by id;
```

**query with auto min / max**

```
   SELECT * FROM topics
    where
      id >= ( SELECT min(id) from topics WHERE name IN('Health & Fitness','Technology'))
    AND
      id <= ( SELECT max(id) from topics WHERE name IN('Health & Fitness','Technology'))
    order by id;
```

Comment: @Strawberry - i have add min /  max in my query, thanks

Comment: That's better :-)

Answer (score -1):

If there are no other fields in the table, then this task can not be solved with some simple syntax. The problem is that data in a relation (table) is unsorted and in general, if you run simple select statements like

```
select * from  topics
```

you may get records in any order.

Whereas, if you have a field, by which you can sort or set a range, then you can try the above solution by Bernd Buffen.

Comment: Bernd Buffen's solution is simple.

Comment: That solution is based on an assumption, that there is id field in the table. And this can't be digested from the main question, since it does not contain schema.